# Casting array to object or stdClass(), which is faster in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object, casting, stdclass

Given the following functions which is faster in PHP or better to use and why?

Casting an array to object:

```
<?php

function() {
    $obj = (object) ['prop1' => 1, 'prop2' => 2]; 

    return $obj;
}
```

Instantiating an `stdClass()`:

```
<?php

function() {
    $obj = new stdClass(); 
    $obj->prop1 = 1; 
    $obj->prop2 = 2;

    return $obj;
}
```

Comment: I've not tested speed but the second one is far more readable in my opinion. Especially if your array is long.

Comment: I'm not sure but: is the first one not using the second one? With extra steps?

Comment: dump the run time and check which one has best benchmark

Comment: @jeroen The assertion being it will take a few million executions to notice the difference I assume. OP worry about something more important

Comment: @RiggsFolly That and to get an average.

Comment: @RiggsFolly diffrence was noticable in few hundred thousand in million is few seconds on "biggish" objects

Comment: @jeroen you could just make the point saying that performance is not a concern in this subject and also that the second option is more readable and understandable. But you prefer to be salty. It's better to have a discussion about something even as simple as this subject.

Answer (score 5):

**My Benchmark** for what its worth

```
function one() {
    $obj = (object) ['prop1' => 1, 'prop2' => 2]; 
    return $obj;
}

function two() {
    $obj = new stdClass(); 
    $obj->prop1 = 1; 
    $obj->prop2 = 2;

    return $obj;
}

$looper = 10000000;

$a = microtime(1);
for ( $i=0; $i < $looper; $i++) { $x = one(); }
$b = microtime(1);
$c = $b-$a;
echo "Using (object) [] method     $looper times " . $c . PHP_EOL;

$a = microtime(1);
for ( $i=0; $i < $looper; $i++) { $x = two(); }
$b = microtime(1);
$d = $b-$a;
echo "Using new stdClass() method $looper times " . $d . PHP_EOL;

echo 'Difference (-ve) means (object) [] is quicker ' . ($c - $d) . PHP_EOL;
```

Results for different versions of PHP

```
PHP7.1.0
Using (object) [] method     10,000,000 times 22.970033168793
Using new stdClass() method 10,000,000 times 38.114390850067
Difference (-ve) means (object) [] is quicker -15.144357681274

PHP7.0.13
Using (object) [] method     10,000,000 times 22.230031967163
Using new stdClass() method 10,000,000 times 29.300040960312
Difference (-ve) means (object) [] is quicker -7.0700089931488


PHP5.6.25
Using (object) [] method     10,000,000 times 47.920066833496
Using new stdClass() method 10,000,000 times 54.20007610321
Difference (-ve) means (object) [] is quicker -6.2800092697144


PHP5.5.36
Using (object) [] method     10,000,000 times 46.450064897537
Using new stdClass() method 10,000,000 times 53.110074043274
Difference (-ve) means (object) [] is quicker -6.6600091457367
```

> The odd thing is that PHP7.1.0 seems to report an appreciably slower `new stdClass() method` than PHP7.0.13

> **Conclusion:** Using the `$obj = (object) ['prop1' => 1, 'prop2' => 2];` method does seem to be quicker.

> **However** I have to loop 10,000 before there is a recordable difference using PHP7, so I am pretty sure there are more important things to worry about.

**UPDATE**
The previous results were generated with XDEBUG turned on. Without XDEBUG it turns out the differences are even less significant and the run times are factor of 10 quicker!

```
**Update for newer releases of PHP**
7.4.12 
Using (object) [] method     10,000,000 times 0.72978782653809
Using new stdClass() method 10,000,000 times 1.3195288181305
Difference (-ve) means (object) [] is quicker -0.58974099159241

7.3.2 
Using (object) [] method     10,000,000 times 0.83337903022766
Using new stdClass() method 10,000,000 times 1.3447999954224
Difference (-ve) means (object) [] is quicker -0.5114209651947

7.0.14
Using (object) [] method     10,000,000 times 2.5900039672852
Using new stdClass() method 10000000 times 3.7700049877167
Difference (-ve) means (object) [] is quicker -1.1800010204315

7.1.0
Using (object) [] method     10,000,000 times 1.8601069450378
Using new stdClass() method 10000000 times 3.215184211731
Difference (-ve) means (object) [] is quicker -1.3550772666931

5.6.28
Using (object) [] method     10,000,000 times 6.0900089740753
Using new stdClass() method 10,000,000 times 6.9300100803375
Difference (-ve) means (object) [] is quicker -0.84000110626221
```

Comment: std class is expensive, however, one can go prototyping approach, but check the result below before :))). What happens when you enlarge data set used ? So i have tested. Tripled data set used (6 elements). For array to object casting, the operational time increased not significantly (~1-2%). However for objects (new AND prototyping), both approaches execution times significantly increased. new stdObject +50%, prototyping +70%.
So the conclusion: use array, as the data set grows - should be even better justification to use array and cast to object. However, now rises question regarding memory

Answer (score 1):

### Benchmark

Using the two methods:

```
<?php

function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

$time_start = microtime_float();

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    // method
}

$time_end = microtime_float();

$time = $time_end - $time_start;

var_dump($time);
```

with this as the `array` method:

```
$obj = (object) ['prop1' => 1, 'prop2' => 2];
```

and this as the `new` method:

```
$obj = new stdClass(); 
$obj->prop1 = 1; 
$obj->prop2 = 2;
```

### Results

I have:

```
float 0.085909843444824 (for the `array` method)
float 0.16712999343872 (for the `new` method)
```

That is, the `array` method is much faster!

### Repetition

Running this code again and again don't change much results.

Comment: Strange, I get the opposite conclusion http://stackoverflow.com/a/41022026/2310830 In all versions of PHP

Comment: you're right, I run my code back on my MBP within the command line and I found the `new` method slower than the `array`... I edit my answer ; I will test this piece of code in my work place again, but it may seams I switched by mistake my results...

Comment: I turned XDEBUG Off and the speed increase was quite stunning.

Answer (score 0):

using this test

```
<?php
$a = microtime();
$obj = (object) ['prop1' => 1, 'prop2' => 2]; 
$b = microtime();
print_r($b-$a);


$a = microtime();
$obj = new stdClass(); 
$obj->prop1 = 1; 
$obj->prop2 = 2;
$b = microtime();
print_r($b-$a);
?>
```

i get for first `2.4E-5` and for second `1.0E-5`
second faster also is more readable and understandable.